# How can I have different views Floating action button on desktop and Mobile for my website?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, floating-action-button

I have a floating action button on the right side of my webpage but when I check it on my mobile, its either completely missing from the page or obstructing the overall view. Ideally, i would want that to stick to the bottom of the page on my mobile. Any tips on how I can do that with HTML and CSS?

Answer (score 0):

You should use media queries in order to display floating action button differently inside smaller or higher resolutions.

You could also analyse `window.navigator` object inside JS and set proper class on  `<body>` so that it can be later used in CSS if you want to differ between physical devices.

In order to know why button is missing I suggest you to connect your phone to debug tools and see what's going on.

Sticking your button to the bottom would be probably achievable with `position: fixed`